# ImageMagick - Using -distort to create curved text with transparent background

Tags: imagemagick

I have a command like this:

> convert -font Tahoma -pointsize 20 label:' Around the World ' \
>             -virtual-pixel Background  -background SkyBlue \
>             -distort Arc 60     arc_circle_1.png

The command will create an image:[image]

The background of the text is white, I want it to be transparent. How can I do that? Tkanks.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you would do that by setting the *undercolor*, like this:

```
convert -undercolor magenta -font Tahoma -pointsize 20 label:' Around the World ' -virtual-pixel Background -background SkyBlue -distort Arc 60  arc_circle_1.png
```

[image]

but for some reason, that doesn't work when you set the undercolour to `none` or `transparent` because you can't overdraw with nothing to make something.

All I can suggest for the minute, is that you create the image with the default white undercolour, then make whites transparent:

```
convert -font Tahoma -pointsize 20 label:' Around the World ' -virtual-pixel Background -background SkyBlue -distort Arc 60 -fuzz 20% -transparent white arc_circle_1.png
```

[image]

If you have whites in your image somewhere, just set the undercolour to fucshia or something very contrasting and later, make that colour transparent.

Comment: insert"-background None" before label.  [please check my question at imagemagick forum](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=31850&p=145600#p145600)